# Error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout

Tags: oracle

i am getting the below error message while using the functionality of external table in oracle.

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "field": expecting one of: "badfile,
byteordermark, characterset, column, data, delimited, discardfile,
disable_directory_link_check, fields, fixed, load, logfile, language,
nodiscardfile, nobadfile, nologfile, date_cache, preprocessor, readsize,
string, skip, territory, variable"
```

Actually, I have created a table by using below command

```
CREATE TABLE SUMIT (
NAME VARCHAR2(20),
AGE INTEGER)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY TEST_FILES ACCESS PARAMETERS (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
FIELD TERMINATED BY ',') LOCATION ('feed.txt'));
```

and table was created successfully. when i am trying to view the contents of the table then i am getting the error. Directory object TEST_FILES is also correct. I have checked 
path as well as file name feed.txt. Below is the structure of feed.txt

```
sumit,123
```

I am using Linux environment. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in all [the examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm), and in the [SQL*Loader documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#sthref683), and in the error message you quoted, it is `fields` not `field`:

```
CREATE TABLE SUMIT (
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  AGE INTEGER
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY TEST_FILES ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  )
  LOCATION ('feed.txt')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response. But i am still getting same error.
`ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04074: no write access to directory object TEST_FILES
`

Comment: @sumitvedi That's a different error message (note the part afer `KUP-04074`). You have to grant the necessary privileges on the directory to the Oracle user that creates the external table.

Comment: Yes...I have also given the permissions...after that i am getting below error msg `ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
error opening file /app/csa/sumit/SUMIT_28715.log
`

Comment: @sumitvedi - does *Oracle* (the operating system owner of the database instance processes) have read/write permission on that directory? It isn't enough for you to have it as the files are written by Oracle, not you. You have to have permissions on the `directory` object `TEST_FILES`; Oracle has to have permissions on the actual file system directory `/app/csa/sumit`.

Comment: Hi Alex I have already given the permission by using below command `GRANT READ,write ON DIRECTORY test_files TO PUBLIC;`

Comment: Test file details 
`OWNER SYS
DIRECTORY_NAME TEST_FILES
DIRECTORY_PATH /app/csa/sumit/`

Comment: @sumitvedi - yes, that gives `directory` permissions to your user (and everyone else). But operating system permissions on the file system directory are a completely separate thing. You need to make sure the `oracle` user in the operating system can write to the directory. Check the owner, group and permissions of the directory and its parent directories, and the group membership of the Oracle operating system account.

Comment: I have checked the parent directory condition its 777 in linux

Comment: @sumitvedi - the permissions on directories higher up the tree can have an impact too. Does `ls -ls /app /app/csa /app/csa/sumit` indicate that Oracle should have at least `r-x` on all of them; or can you try to create a file directly in that directory as the `oracle` user?