# Getting error on server side while executing query

Tags: java, sql, oracle

We have one JAVA Application which has ETL process. When we execute that ETL process, zip file is unzip which contains many csv file. And this using this csv file, we load data into external tables. While loading data to external table we are getting following error.

```
 CREATE TABLE "EXTERNAL_TABLE" 
   (    "column1" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "column2" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "column3" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "EXT_DIRECTORY"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\n'
    BADFILE EXT_DIRECTORY:'test.bad'
    DISCARDFILE EXT_DIRECTORY:'test.dsc'
    SKIP 1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
    LRTRIM
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL (
    column1 CHAR(4000),    column2 CHAR(4000),    column3 CHAR(4000)    )
      )
      LOCATION
       ( 'test.csv'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: error occurred during batching: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file test.csv in TEST_TBL not found at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeBatch(OracleStatement.java:4615)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem.
What did you try? What is the expected result? Can you show us some code?
Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it.
Thank you!

Comment: An what have you been trying to do? Seems like your TEST_TBL is not accessible. Are you trying to use external tables like described here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/examples-using-oracle-external-tables.html It's hard to help if you don'let us know what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is raised when the database attempts to access an external table and the file which is called for in the external table definition doesn't exist or is inaccessible. In this case the file it's looking for is `test.csv`, which is supposed to exist in a directory whose name in the database is `TEST_TBL`. You might try writing a test procedure to see if you can open and read this file using the `UTL_FILE` package.

Due to lack of details it's difficult to say if any of the other answers on this site which refer to similar problems apply in your case, but you might look at the following:

[ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50474822/ora-29913-error-in-executing-odciexttableopen-callout)

[sqlplus error on select from external table: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066191/sqlplus-error-on-select-from-external-table-ora-29913-error-in-executing-odcie)

[Error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488204/error-in-executing-odciexttableopen-callout)